# Is it possible to support multiple domain names on a single web application?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting

My goal is to create a service that will allow someone to register their own domain (so, many domains being used), and have that domain point to a specific service/template within a single web application.

Is this possible using URL rewriting or some other method? I want to have a vanity domain that would essentially act as the unique identifier within my application...

So instead of www.myapplicationdomain.com/site/1 and www.myapplicationdomain.com/site/2, i could allow a vanity domain that my application would utilize.

- www.customwdomain.com = application/site/1
- www.bettercustomwdomain.com = application/site/2

Is this possible, or would i essentially have to dynamically create new websites in IIS and drop files in those folders that the domain would point to? I know IIS can support multiple websites on the same host, but I was trying to take it a step further.

I guess my question is very similar to this question:
[IIS with multiple domains on one single web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002200/iis-with-multiple-domains-on-one-single-web-application)

Some considerations:

- Trying to make this work on Azure shared hosting
- I don't want to use sub-domains
- I want the vanity domain to always be in use (e.g. not a redirect)

Comment: check it, it's helpful to you [blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/iis-url-rewrite-hosting-multiple-domains-under-one-site)

Comment: I don't think that addresses what I'm trying to do. I'm not trying to host multiple domains on one server, I'm trying to have one application recognize and react to multiple domains - not sure it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

We have an Ecommerce web application that has many web domains being pointed to it, each with their own unique interface. This is entirely dependent on technologies of the Apache software foundation, and I'm not aware of a way to do this without a web server sorting out domains for the application.

1. We rely on Apache HTTP server for Virtualhost configurations (the listener & configs for each domain), and for serving static content.
2. We rely on Apache Tomcat for the single Java app that displays most of the interface and functionality. The Apache HTTP server is configured to pass relevant traffic to the Java app.

Answer (score 0):

Configure multiple custom domains to an web-app and then add application gateway at the front of the application. Now based on the application url redirect to the updated url of the website.